# HDiv redirecting to error page Error[HDIV_PARAMETER_DOES_NOT_EXIST]

Tags: struts-1, hdiv

**Running Struts 1.3.8**

hdiv-config.xml

```
<hdiv:config excludedExtensions="css,png,js,gif,jpeg"
    protectedExtensions=".*.do" maxPagesPerSession="20" confidentiality="true" avoidCookiesIntegrity="true">        
    <hdiv:startPages>/loginForm.do</hdiv:startPages>
    <hdiv:startPages>/login.do</hdiv:startPages>
    <hdiv:startPages>/logout.do</hdiv:startPages>

    <hdiv:startPages>/home.do</hdiv:startPages>
    <hdiv:startPages>/pages/BillDischarge/NewPrepaidBill.do</hdiv:startPages>


    <hdiv:startParameters>org.apache.struts.action.TOKEN,org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN</hdiv:startParameters>
</hdiv:config>
    <hdiv:editableValidations>
    <hdiv:validationRule url=".*"/>
</hdiv:editableValidations>
```

`

Every page except the ones defined under startPages redirects me to the 'Unauthorized' Error Page.

Log:
`2016-10-19 14:42:10 [@] INFO  Logger: HDIV_PARAMETER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;/pages/Common/PatientSearch.do;_HDIV_STATE_;;;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;anonymous;`

Help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your link and forms are not processed by Hdiv.

Check the configuration of the tag libraries. The application have to load Hdiv tld files instead of Struts's ones.

Have a look at this example application for a working web.xml file: 
https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-struts-examples/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L122